# Nested Columns of gridview in asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

My gridview has 5 columns. In the first column, I wish to have 4 inner or nested columns. Kindly give me possible solution. Please find attached Image depicting the actual problem and the way I want it to be done.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Either you must use nested `GridViews` like @Dusht wrote, or you can stop using `GridView` and use a `ListView` instead. With `ListView` you can render a table with more columns, but set the colspan on the header row so that the header covers several columns of row data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create nested gridview. Please refer to below link to achieve this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20047/Editable-Nested-GridView-All-in-One

Comment: @NikhilBhumkar You are Welcome. Please mark it as answer and upvote it if it serves your purpose. Thanks